# Json array from JSON response is always null

Tags: java, json, rest, gson, jersey-2.0

I am working on rest client program in which I am parsing a json response using gson. My json response is as below

```
{
    "Status": "success",

    "Data": [
        {
            "ID": "123",
            "Type": 0,
            "OperatorID": null,
            "DepartmentID": "128",
            "LanguageCode": "en-US",
            "WebsiteDefID": "160",
            "VisitID": "737",
        },
        {
            "ID": "737867804181437078",
            "Type": 0,
            "OperatorID": "1785",
            "DepartmentID": "200",
            "LanguageCode": "en-US",
            "WebsiteDefID": "160",
            "VisitID": "737",
            "CustomFields": {
                "Model": "ABCD",
                "Question": "ABCD"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Gson:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson= gsonBuilder.create();
Info info = gson.fromJson(inactiveChatMessages, Info.class);
```

And my `Info` and `Data` Pojo class is as below:

```
public class Info {
    private String Status;

    private Data[] Data;

    public String getStatus() {
        return Status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        Status = status;
    }

    public Data[] getData() {
        return Data;
    }
    public void setData(Data[] data) {
        Data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ChatInfo [Status=" + Status + ",  Data=" + Arrays.toString(Data) + "]";
    }
}
```

Data:

```
public class Data {
    private String ID;
    private String OperatorID;
    private String DepartmentID;


    private CustomFields CustomFields;

    public String getID() {
        return ChatID;
    }
    public void setID(String ID) {
        ChatID = chatID;
    }
    public String getOperatorID() {
        return OperatorID;
    }
    public void setOperatorID(String operatorID) {
        OperatorID = operatorID;
    }
    public String getDepartmentID() {
        return DepartmentID;
    }
    public void setDepartmentID(String departmentID) {
        DepartmentID = departmentID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [ID=" + ID + ", OperatorID=" + OperatorID + ", DepartmentID=" + DepartmentID + ", CustomFields=" + CustomFields
                + "]";
    }
}
```

In `Data` pojo from array I am only accessing the fields which I need. But in response I am always getting data array as null. There is no error. So I am really not getting exactly what is going wrong. Can anyone please help me with this?

```
Info [Status=success, Data=[]]
```

Comment: use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate POJO, it seems your POJO not valid for GSON it need @SerializableName("param") anotation

Comment: I have tried by giving it. But no luck

Comment: please correct your jason once using https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is not valid

Your valid json.

```
{
    "Status": "success",

    "Data": [{
            "ID": "123",
            "Type": 0,
            "OperatorID": null,
            "DepartmentID": "128",
            "LanguageCode": "en-US",
            "WebsiteDefID": "160",
            "VisitID": "737"

        },
        {
            "ID": "737867804181437078",
            "Type": 0,
            "OperatorID": "1785",
            "DepartmentID": "200",
            "LanguageCode": "en-US",
            "WebsiteDefID": "160",
            "VisitID": "737",
            "CustomFields": {
                "Model": "ABCD",
                "Question": "ABCD"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

for json validation you can use https://jsonlint.com/

otherwise your code is working fine.

here is output

```
ChatInfo [Status=success,  Data=[Data [ID=123, OperatorID=null, DepartmentID=128, CustomFields=null], Data [ID=737867804181437078, OperatorID=1785, DepartmentID=200, CustomFields=[Model=ABCD,question=ABCD]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Dhiraj. I am accessing Rest URL from our client and it is valid. Problem here is even it is working fine in my local. But when I am deploying it in jboss server it is not working. That is very confusing for me.

Comment: so when you hit REST url  you will get above JSON?

Comment: yes in local envirnment I am getting responce but in jboss server responce is always blank.  I am using Jersey 2 jars

Comment: so its not your json problem, its rest url problem. try to hit your rest url from postman